# Google sheets timestamp via apps script dropdown

Tags: google-apps-script, timestamp

First of all I would like to thank Monke_Ed for this great script. I found this script a last year and modififed it a bit for our workload distribution sheet it is supposed to add time stamps to COL "Accuracy Check" and COL "Offer Extended" when row 13 of the current worksheet is edited.
It was working as needed when it stopped working all of a sudden with the Execution log below is which refers to the "addtimestamp(e)" line.
I'm at a loss on what to do here. Please help.

I double checked the code I copied it correctly thank you for looking into this.

```
Execution log
8:51:29 AM  Notice  Execution started
8:51:37 AM  Error   
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getRow')
addTimestamp    @ timeStamp.gs:14
onEdit  @ timeStamp.gs:3
```

```
function onEdit(e) {
  
  addTimestamp(e);
    
}

function addTimestamp(e){
  //variables
  var startRow = 13;
  var targetColumn = 13; 
  var ws = "2023";
  
  //target row and column  
  var row = addTimestamp.range.getRow();
  var col = addTimestamp.range.getColumn();
  var currentDate = new Date();
  
  if(col === targetColumn && row>= startRow && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName()=== ws){
    
    if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,13).getValue() =="Accuracy Check"){
       e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,14).setValue(currentDate);
    }
    if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,13).getValue() =="Offer Extended"){
      e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,15).setValue(currentDate);
    } //END IF  
  }//END IF 
}//END function addTimestamp
```

I apologize for not doing anything relevant  I'm pretty new and still learning google scripts and really can.t figure out what needs to be done I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the "addtimestamp(e)" line.

Just to add more detail in my question all I want to do is to add a timestamp in COL O if "Offer Extended" is selected in COL M and another Time Stamp in COL N if "Accuracy Check" is selected in COL M.
[MySpread Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZW1SO.png)

Comment: In your script, shouldn't `addTimestamp.range` be `e.range`? But, you say `it was working fine until a January 17, 2023`. So, I'm worried that you might have miscopied your script. How about this?

Comment: NelsonN, as @Rubén points out, my choice of language describing your script was, shall we say, hyperbolic. I apologise if I gave you cause for concern; "seriously corrupted" is perhaps a little over the top. OTOH, it _is_ the case that there are some problems in your script and I _do_ think it is best that we go back to basics, and that you please edit your question to describe EXACTLY and COMPLETELY what the script is supposed to do.

Comment: Hi @Tedinoz sorry for not being clear I modified my question. I use the script to add timestamps to a COL when a cell gets edited. As I mentioned before that same script was working before then it suddenly stopped.

Comment: Hi I also added an image for clarity on my issue

Comment: Hi @Tedinoz and Tanaike, Thank you very much for taking your time to look into this and my apologies for my mistakes when asking my questions here. I was able to make the script again by just retyping the first 3 lines that is "function onEdit(e) {
addTimestamp(e);
}" tho I'm still trying to find out what happened, but I'm happy that it is working again.

Comment: So, you're saying that you left these two lines intact: `var row = addTimestamp.range.getRow();` and `var col = addTimestamp.range.getColumn();`. And the script works? I'm not sure that I understand that. @Tanaike does that make sense to you?

Comment: @Tedinoz I think that when I saw your answer now, it is the correct answer. So, I also cannot understand OP's reply. I'm worried that OP might have changed the script from the currently showing script. But, I cannot know about it. So, how about asking about the OP's current script?

Comment: @NelsoN would you clarify whether the script described in the question is your actual, real script. If you have only retyped the `onEdit` function, then it doesn't explain how `var row` and `var col` could have processed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your script does not work because these two lines fail.

- `var row = addTimestamp.range.getRow();`
- `var col = addTimestamp.range.getColumn();`

The reason is that `addTimestamp`has no meaning in this context

In the answer below, these have been replaced by

- `var row = e.range.rowStart`
- `var col = e.range.columnStart`

There can only be one reason that your script stopped working - that is, someone edited (knowingly or accidentally) those two lines of code.

---

```
function onEdit(e) {
  addTimestamp(e);
}

function addTimestamp(e){ 
  //variables
  var startRow = 13;
  var targetColumn = 13; 
  var ws = "2023";
  
  // get the edited row and the edited column
  var row = e.range.rowStart
  var col = e.range.columnStart
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: Edited row:"+row+", edited column:"+col) 
  
  var currentDate = new Date();

  // test whether the edited cell  was in Column M and row>=13 on sheet: 2023
  if(col === targetColumn && row>= startRow && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === ws){   
    // Correct column, row & right sheet
    if(e.value ==="Accuracy Check"){
       e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,14).setValue(currentDate);
    }
    if(e.value ==="Offer Extended"){
      e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,15).setValue(currentDate);
    } //END IF  
  }//END IF 
}//END function addTimestamp
```